# Copy Column and Paste in different sheet starting at row 15 then every 87th row after

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a column (Sheet 2, range("A6:A70") and paste in Sheet 1. I want the value in Sheet 2 A6 to paste in Sheet 1 A15, then the value in Sheet 2 A7 to paste 87 rows below A 15, and so on pasting the whole column(Sheet 2, A6:A70) every 87th cell in sheet 1.

I have tried different .offset commands and

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

but what i need the loop to do is

start at A15 and paste first value

then maybe:

Read where last paste was, move 87 rows down, paste next value, etc...

```
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

copySheet.Range("A6:A70").Copy

pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(87, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

actual results are nothing - i am unsure what code i should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like this perhaps:

```
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim i as Long
For i = 0 to 64
    pasteSheet.Range("A15").Offset(i * 87).Value = copySheet.Range("A6").Offset(i).Value
Next i
```

**EDIT:**

If you're dealing with merged cells in the `pasteSheet`, try

```
pasteSheet.Cells(15 + i*87, 1).Value = copySheet.Range("A6").Offset(i).Value
```

Comment: That works perfectly on a blank sheet! Definitely a step in the right direction. My problem is when i paste into Sheet2 cell A15 is a merged cell (A15:A17) and 87 cells lower is another merged cell (A102:A104) etc..... For some reason it is pasting the A15 cell perfectly and it does not paste the remainder of the cells. If I change the offset to 86 or 90 it will paste as programmed but that is not the correct cell. Could it be because the merged cells throw off the offset count?

Comment: Merged cells shouldn't throw off the count. You refer to a merged cell by its leftmost, uppermost cell, so `A102` would be the cell value to update. Step through the code with `F8`. What exactly happens for all the cells besides `A15`?

Comment: Nothing, as far as i can tell. The step for the first iteration pastes in A15, then it runs through iterations but nothing happens on the sheet.

Comment: When i change my pasteSheet to a blank sheet it works exactly as intended, pasting in A15, A102, etc.... and the merged cells are top left A15, A102, etc...

Comment: I understand what is happening. It is taking the merged cell as one cell. If i removed the merged cell at 102:104 it pastes the second iteration in 104. I believe it is taking A15:A17 as a single cell for the offset count - so while it is offsetting 87 it is starting at A17, not A15.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right, interesting, learned something new. In that case you need to adjust the offset. Or you can use `.Cells(15 + i*87, 1).Value` instead of `Range("A15").Offset(i * 87).Value`.

Comment: Try the `.Cells(15 + i*87, 1).Value`. Might be easier than adjusting the Offset.

Comment: I did but since I do not have 15 reputation it is not publicly displayed. It says the answer was still recorded though. - check mark is green though. Thanks!